# Strength, weight, cost comparison for Aluminum vs. Framing Lumber floor joists

Tags: floor, framing

I'm considering using Aluminum (I beams or other shapes) instead of Framing Lumber as the material for the floor joists in a residential remodeling job. The finished floor I intend to support with these joists is traditional hardwood and I would be seeking residential code compliance; nothing more demanding than that.

Can anyone point me to authoritative documents that would allow me to compare the strength (pounds per linear foot), and weight of the two different materials in several shapes (I beam or other)?

I'm certain that Aluminum will have higher strength and lower weight than typical Framing Lumber, but I'd like to see specific numbers.

I'm really just looking to try and get a feeling for options (materials and shapes) and to understand the implications of each option.

Comment: Shopping questions (e.g. links to suppliers) are off-topic, since they are very region-dependent and change often. I'd remove that portion of your question. Cost considerations are off-topic, too, for the same reasons, although generalizations might be able to be made (e.g., aluminum is / isn't generally more expensive than lumber), so you may need to edit that portion out as well.

Comment: Besides being a shopping question, this is actually a question for whoever is engineering your remodel. Locale to locale varies, but from most of what I have seen, anytime you are not just simply replacing the same board for an equivalent product, you need an engineer and inspection. This is not REALLY a DIY question, since it would need professional sign-off in most places where you're changing joists, and therefore loadbearing structures.

Comment: What's driving you to consider aluminum vs traditional framing lumber?  Typically, weight of framing members isn't a significant concern for residential construction.  Strength is of course, but unless you have a unique restriction on the depth of the joist, typical 2xN joists or engineered I joists or trusses should be adequate.  Going to aluminum joists will certainly complicate things - can't nail to them, everything about how you use them will have to be signed off by an engineer - span, placement, cutouts, attachment, etc.

Comment: Aluminum isn't typically a structural building component material. Steel is probably what you're after.

Comment: I'm interested in Aluminum primarily because I'm trying to minimize the weight and also increase the strength above lumber joists. [This page](http://www.aluma.com/us/products/formwork_shoring/shoring/aluminum_joists_and_stringers) presents an example of what I'm interested in using, but I think this link is primarily for commercial versus my intended residential use. Thanks for all the feedback.

Comment: @Osteoboon Is this for a floating, moving, or flying structure? What is the primary drive to reduce weight? The only place I've seen non-commercial applications like this were for floating houses in TN.

Comment: The link indicates that the use of aluminum would be for support of temporary scaffolding in which the lower weight would make repeated assembly and disassembly easier.

Comment: Also "Tiny homes" built on a trailer to evade minimum-square-footage building codes, but whicha rea actually hauled around (since they can be) is another example where lightness + strength is a virtue.   The problem I see is that your terrestrial building needs to pass muster with the building inspector, and they notoriously hate anything different.  Just try building an Earthship.

Comment: Whether you use aluminum or steel, there's also a considerable difference in fire performance - metal beams don't burn, but they do fail (often faster than wood) as they get hot, so protecting the framing with insulation is typically required.

Comment: BrownRedHawk this is for a typical stationary residential home that was originally built with lumber framing material. The primary drive to reduce weight is exploratory; to study options, tradeoffs, etc. A floating house seems very interesting to me and a project that I'd enjoy experimenting with someday, but not in the near future. Jim_Stewart, I thought I knew what joists and stringers were; if that link is actually describing temporary scaffolding, then maybe there are no products like what I have in mind. Thanks for pointing that out. Harper and Ecnerwal those are good points; thank you!